# Enable Secuirty in WAS 6.1

Tags: websphere

In WAS6.1, when I try to check the 'Enable Administrative Security' under 'Secure administration, applications, and infrastructure '. I get error:

```
You must supply the primary administrative user name on the active registry or realm panels to enable security.
```

What is the realm panel/ active registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to recreate your profile. On the same page of the admin console, at the bottom, have a look at "User account repository". Choose your realm definition in "Available realm definitions". Click on "configure", you then set the "Primary administrative user name" there. Once you saved, you must "Set as current" the chosen definition then save to the master configuration and restart your server.

Comment: I get "Validation failed: Access is denied" trying to "Enable administrative security" after doing this, even after restarting.  I set the primary admin name to be the same as the user I was currently logged in as.  When I try to log out and back in, it only prompts me for the user name, no password.

Answer (score 0):

A Realm is a "database" of usernames and passwords that identify valid users of a web application (or set of web applications).

the system is expecting you to enter your admin password, so that the websphere instance can start to update its base configuration (in this case to include administrative security).

Comment: Thanks. When I login to admin console, it does not prompt for password. Just prompts for username. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The WAS profile did not have Security enabled. Creating a new profile with Security Enabled solved the problem